# ¿Cómo eliminar un registro de una mat table con Angular a traves de un boton?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Tengo la siguiente tabla donde se puede editar el contenido del campo **descripción**, y a traves del icono **Delete** se puede eliminar el registro seleccionado, pero lo hace visualmente nada más, es decir, solo desaparece de la pantalla, pero en si en la BD sigue estando el registro, y lo que quiero  es que se elimine de la BD a traves del servicio que ya tengo creado, pero que al hacer click en el icono de **Delete**, primero te mande un msj que diga, seguro que deseas eliminar el registro? y que tenga el boton de Aceptar/cancelar

mi html

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
                <button mat-raised-button class="buttonUpdate" color="primary"
                    (click)="obtenerProductos()">Actualizar
                    <mat-icon>update</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title class="text">
                        Productos
                    </mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <div class="scrollme">
                    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceProd" class="mat-elevation-z8">

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID  </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="descripcion">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DESCRIPCIÓN </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                <mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
                                    <input matInput type="text" [value]="element.descripcion"
                                        (keyup)="changeValueDescTipo($event.target,element)"
                                        [disabled]="!element.editable">
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="botonEdit">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> EDITAR </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="actualizarProd(element)">
                                    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="botonDelete">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ELIMINAR </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                <button mat-icon-button color="warn"
                                (click)="eliminarProductos($event.target,element)">
                                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsProd"></tr>
                        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsProd">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <mat-paginator #paginatorCatalogos [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5]"
                    showFirstLastButtons>
                </mat-paginator>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
```

component.ts

```
 displayedColumnsProd: string[] = ['id', 'descripcion', 'botonEdit', 'botonDelete'];

    dataSourceProd: any;
    obtenerProductos() {
    this.productService.obtenerProducto().subscribe(response => {
      if (response.data.length == 0) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          text: 'Sin datos '
        })
      } else {
        this.tipoProducto = response.data;
        this.dataSourceProd = new MatTableDataSource(this.tipoProducto);
        this.dataSourceProd.paginatorCatalogos = this.paginatorCatalogos;
      }

    });
  }
  
  //obtiene el valor de la descripcion 
  changeValueDescTipo(e: any, row: any) {
    this.idSelecc = row.id;
    this.tipoProductoDesc = e.value;
  }
  
  eliminarProductos(element: any,row: any) {
const index = this.dataSourceProd.data.indexOf(element);
this.dataSourceProd.data.splice(index);
this.dataSourceProd = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataSourceProd.data);

this.tipoProducto.id = row.id;
this.productService.eliminarProducto(this.tipoProducto).subscribe(response => {
  Swal.fire({
    icon: 'success',
    title: 'Éxito',
    text: '¿Seguro que deseas eliminar el registro?'
  });
});
```

}

Este es el servicio que elimina por ID el registro en la base datos

service.ts

```
eliminarProducto(tipoProducto: Producto){
    return this.httpClient.delete<Producto>(this.baseUrl+"/"+tipoProducto.id);
  }
```

lo que no sé,  es como implementar en mi método **eliminarProductos()** el servicio que elimina por id el registro en la base de datos , pero que antes muestre una alerta para confirmar que se desea eliminar

Comment: `this.llamadaATuServicio(idDelProducto);` debería de permitirte llamarlo. En cuanto a la alerta, pues depende de qué alerta quieras mostrar, si vas a usar un componente propio, uno nativo o uno de angular material. No podemos hacer las cosas por ti, así que te recomiendo que elijas qué componente quieres usar para mostrar la alerta, lo intentes hacer y si tienes un problema concreto vengas a preguntar. "No se cómo hacerlo" por desgracia no es un problema concreto, es más un problema de no haber investigado e intentado algo, requisito obligatorio a la hora de abrir una pregunta en SO.

Comment: @Benito-B,  Ya agregué el servicio y ya elimina el registro desde BD,y agregue para el mensaje Swal.fire, pero cuando manda el mensaje de confirmación, ya se hizo la eliminación, actualice mi pregunta

Comment: En eliminarProductos de donde sacas el row.id? Mandas un element del tipo any pero no veo de dónde sale row.

Comment: @René Ya actualice el html y el método eliminarProductos, solo que no sé en que momento colocar el mensaje de confirmación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver el problema tienes que esperar a que se resuelva la promesa de SweetAlert por lo que necesitas un método asíncrono, código como ejemplo:

**HTML**

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Acciones">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Acciones</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="guardar(row)">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="eliminar(row)">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

**Componente**

```
  async eliminar(row: any) {
    const deleteAlert = await Swal.fire({
      title: 'Eliminar registro',
      showDenyButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Eliminar',
    });

    if (deleteAlert.isConfirmed) {
      // Aquí agregas el código para eliminar el registro
    }
  }
```

Y de dónde sale `isConfirmed`? Si haces un `console.log` de `deleteAlert` vas a ver que tiene las siguientes propiedades: `isConfirmed`, `isDenied`, `isDismissed` y `value`, entonces cuando aceptas en el dialogo que aparece `isConfirmed` es `true`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: YA LO APLIQUE, GRACIAS!!!!